# OnCollisionEnter Change Text when triggered

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm very new to Unity, but not to C#. I'm looking to make a simple solution where when i move a ball into a hole - an event is triggered. The event in this case is changing the text of a TMPro object. I'm seeing nothing being returned when these 2 objects interact using the below code.... Looking for any help on this. More context can be given if needed.

Hole.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
public class Hole : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Update is called once per frame    
    [SerializeField]
    private Collision collision;
    private TextMeshProUGUI text;
    private void Start()
    {
        text = GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
    }    
    void Update()
    {                
        //text.text = "Hole hit!";
    }
    public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {        
        text.text = "Hole hit!";

    }

}
```

BallMover.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BallMover : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(horizontal, vertical);
        transform.position += movement * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

The Error below "Object Reference not set to instance of an object" is coming up when these 2 object collide...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to check are there colliders in both objects.
2. Collision is a physical event for this reason you have to move the ball with physics, if you move it with transform, it is very likely that you will miss the physics events.
3. You have to add a "Rigidbody" component to the ball to move physically.

Comment: Hi, @bmoglu. I have RigidBody objects for both the objects. Nothing is happening when they collide

Comment: If you share photos from the hierarchy, we can understand the problem more easily.
There may also be a problem with the object the script is attached to.

Answer (score 0):

So as you said in a comment you already checked that

- You are using `Rigidbody`
- Both objects have `Collider` components

So additionally make sure

- both `Collider` components are set to `IsTrigger = false`
- Whenever there is physics and `Rigidbody` involved you do not want to set stuff via `transform` in `Update` as this breaks the physics and collision detection! Rather use [`Rigidbody.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) within [`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html)

so something like e.g.

```c#
public class BallMover : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody _rigidbody;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        if(!_rigidbody) _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        var horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        var vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        var movement = new Vector3(horizontal, vertical);
        _rigidbody.MovePosition(_rigidbody.position + movement * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and updated the post above. Still having an error. Thanks

Comment: Well what you get is a classical `NullReferenceException` meaning that you are trying to access something on a reference that is `null` .. there is no `TextMeshProUGUI` component attached to the `Hole` ... So `GetComponent` will return `null` for that ...

Comment: Well, this does work fine if i put the text changing component inside the Update function so that isn't the issue. It finds it perfectly, just not when the object is collided with...

Comment: But there is nothing else happening in your `OnCollisionEnter` .. so it has to be that `text` that isn't assigned in that moment for what reason ever ... The error message should tell you exactly from which script and which line it is thrown